# Should I caulk the baseboards to sheet vinyl floor in a basement bathroom?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I'm planning to install sheet vinyl first and then install the baseboards directly on top. Would it be a good idea to put a bead of caulk there to keep water from getting in between? This is a basement bathroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re not installing cove base, I would definitely caulk the base to the sheet vinyl...or make sure you never allow teenage girls in your basement bathroom.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue with children in general. My son can drive a car, but still manages to somehow soak the floor when he showers.